# A simple strtod() example in c

Tags: c

When I read [strtod() example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) , I have some doubt. Here is the code:

```
const char *p = "111.11 -2.22 Nan nan(2) inF 0X1.BC70A3D70A3D7P+6  1.18973e+4932zzz";
printf("Parsing '%s':\n", p);
char *end;
double f; 
for (f = strtod(p, &end); p != end; f = strtod(p, &end))
{
    printf("'%.*s' -> ", (int)(end-p), p);//I can't understand this line
    p = end;
    if (errno == ERANGE){
        printf("range error, got ");
        errno = 0;
    }
    printf("%f\n", f);
}
```

Output:

```
Parsing '111.11 -2.22 Nan nan(2) inF 0X1.BC70A3D70A3D7P+6  1.18973e+4932zzz':
'111.11' -> 111.110000
' -2.22' -> -2.220000
' Nan' -> 1.#QNAN0
' nan(2)' -> 1.#SNAN0
' inF' -> 1.#INF00
' 0X1.BC70A3D70A3D7P+6' -> 111.110000
'  1.18973e+4932' -> range error, got 1.#INF00
```

Why can `end - p`  get a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtod(p, &end)` sets `end` to point to the next byte after the number that was parsed. So when you make this call with the initial string, the result is:

```
111.11 -2.22 Nan nan(2) inF 0X1.BC70A3D70A3D7P+6  1.18973e+4932zzz
^     ^
p    end
```

`end-p` is then the length of the number that was parsed. When you write

```
printf("'%.*s' -> ", (int)(end-p), p);
```

this length is used for the `.*` size of the `%s` field, which makes it only print that many bytes of the string.

The loop then sets `p = end` and repeats, so this time you get:

```
111.11 -2.22 Nan nan(2) inF 0X1.BC70A3D70A3D7P+6  1.18973e+4932zzz
      ^     ^
      p    end
```

The loop keeps doing this to find each number in the string. If it can't parse a number at the location in the string, it sets `end` to point to the input string, and the test `p != end` fails, so the loop ends.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.